# How to use CLIPSNet

Tags: c#, clips

I am trying to integrate CLIPS with C#,I have tried adding a reference to CLIPSNet.dll in my project.But when I copy the CLIPSLib.dll to the bin folder and try to bulid the solution I get this error message,

Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'CLIPSLib' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E) at CLIPSNet.Environment.CreateEnvironment(Int32 env) at CLIPSNet.Environment..ctor() at herbicide.Program.Main(String[] args) in ..\repos\herbicide\Program.cs:line 9

How do I fix this so as to successfully run CLIPS from c#

the code:

```
using System;
 
namespace herbicide 
{ class Program 
   { static void Main(string[] args) 
       CLIPSNet.Environment theEnv = new CLIPSNet.Environment(); 
        theEnv.Load(@"Herbicide.clp"); 
        theEnv.Reset(); 
        theEnv.Run(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: https://csharp.developreference.com/article/23552015/Can+not+load+the+CLIPSLIB.dll+file+with+Windows+Service suggests there may be two different DLLs that you need.

Comment: Where did you download CLIPSNET from?